# Repository pattern Generic Write Repository issue - Object State Manager Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, asp.net-mvc-5

I am doing an MVC project using a repository pattern and I have a core write repository as follows

```
public abstract class WriteRepository<TContext> : IWriteRepository
   where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    private readonly TContext _context;

    protected TContext Context { get { return _context; } }

    protected WriteRepository()
    {
        _context = new TContext();
    }

    public TItem Update<TItem>(TItem item, bool saveImmediately = true) where TItem : class, new()
    {
        return PerformAction(item, EntityState.Modified, saveImmediately);
    }

    public TItem Delete<TItem>(TItem item, bool saveImmediately = true) where TItem : class, new()
    {
        return PerformAction(item, EntityState.Deleted, saveImmediately);
    }

    public TItem Insert<TItem>(TItem item, bool saveImmediately = true) where TItem : class, new()
    {
        return PerformAction(item, EntityState.Added, saveImmediately);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected virtual TItem PerformAction<TItem>(TItem item, EntityState entityState, bool saveImmediately = true) where TItem : class, new()
    {
       _context.Entry(item).State = entityState;
        if (saveImmediately)
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return item;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I wanted to update a single field in my db on an action method and I was doing a get all before I could update that value like below

```
  public ActionResult UpdateTenant(string id)
    {
        Tenant model = new Tenant();
        model = _TenantServices.GetItemById(Guid.Parse(id));
        model.IsLoginEnabled = true;
        _TenantServices.Update(model);
        return RedirectToAction("ViewDetails", new { id = model.TenantId });
    }
```

When I do that I am getting an error saying "***An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."***

I am using AsNoTracking to retrieve data as follow

```
 public Tenant GetItemById(Guid id)
 {
            return Context.Tenants.AsNoTracking().Where(t => t.TenantId == id).FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

Any Idea how can I solve this ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I am getting an error on this line _context.Entry(item).State = entityState;

Should I just assign it to a var model = _TenantServices.GetItemById(Guid.Parse(id)); ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman The issue was with my Tenant Repository class, as you mentioned there was nothing wrong with the code I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you retrieve an object from the database, Entity Framework begins tracking (attaches) the object immediately. You will be able to make changes to the retrieved object (i.e. set property values) and call `SaveChanges()` so that the object will be updated in the database, without the need to set the `EntityState`.

And in fact, if you attempt to `Attach` or set the `EntityState` of an already-tracked object, you will get the error you mentioned above.

So, to resolve the error, you can:

- Use one instance of of your `TContext` to retrieve and another instance to update. In this case, you should attach and set the `EntityState` in the update method for the changes to get persisted.
- Use a single instance of your `TContext` to retrieve and update, but don't attempt to `Attach` or to set the `EntityState` anymore. Call `SaveChanges` directly after setting the property values.
- Use a single instance of your `TContext`, but when retrieving the record you can call `AsNoTracking()`. This will allow you to safely `Attach` or set `EntityState` during the update.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have multiple Context in the project will that be an issue ? I am retrieving the data asnotracking but it doesn't seems to have much effect as well

Comment: The issue you are describing can happen even when you only have a single class that inherits from `DbContext`. And even if you had multiple context classes, I believe there is only one context class that holds your Tenant `DbSet` (please confirm?).

Comment: Yeah there is only one dbcontext

Comment: See the edit I am using AsNotracking but still no luck